# B43 driver installation problems

Tags: wireless

So, I'm attempting to install the wireless driver for my *bc4311* wireless card using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

But I get to see the following message:

```
Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update  first?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 12.04 or higher just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to find the package respective to your version at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firmware-b43-installer, select the appropriate architecture, download, and install through Ubuntu Software Center or

sudo dpkg -i [path to downloaded file]

Also make sure you have the dependencies.